# How to connect to redis sentinel and manipulate different dbs

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cli

I am struggling to connect redis in sentinel mode using redis-cli.

I've tried:

`redis-cli -h my_host -p my_port -a my_password`

I randomly picked up one from 3 sentinel nodes to connect.

However, when logged in, it seems different with single mode redis, where I can manipulate dbs with `set` or `hset` commmand.

For instance, when I am typing:

`select 0` (trying to select db 0)

It returns:

```
redis_sentinel_node_1_ip:port> select 0
(error) ERR unknown command `select`, with args beginning with: `0`
```

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Sentinel and Redis use the same communication protocol (and live in the same executable as well), they support a very different set of commands. Afaik, Sentinel does not have the notion of multiple databases, so `SELECT` wouldn't have any sense there. If you just want to test a random command, you can use `PING` which is supported by both Redis and Sentinel.

You may want to review the set of commands Sentinel supports on the [official docs](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#sentinel-commands).

Comment: thanks. It turns out that i was confused by the difference between the set of sentinel commands and the set of traditional redis commands. I've used `SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name <master name>` to discover the master node, and then, use the information returned, I was able to successfully connect to the master node.